# "Traduzir" query do MySQL para o SQL Server 2012

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server, query

Qual a query do SQL Server 2012 que corresponde à query seguinte do MySQL?

```sql
REPLACE INTO schedule SET jobname = "sqldump" , last_exec_date = NOW()
```

Comment: As vezes o site: http://www.sqlines.com/online ajuda a converter, as vezes. a resposta abaixo do @Daniel, está bem completa.

Comment: Qual o nome da coluna que é a chave primária da tabela [schedule]? Quais outras colunas existem na tabela? Como está declarada a coluna last_exec_date?

Comment: O que você esta querendo fazer? um update?

Comment: @MarconcilioSouza Isso mesmo

Comment: @JoséDiz A chave primária é `job_id`

Comment: @David Pois é, mas o `REPLACE INTO` não tá dando certo. Eu usei o *Microsoft SQL Server Migration Assistant for MySQL* para converter todas as outras queries, mas essa não tá sendo "traduzida"

Comment: @NotTheRealHemingway: Se puder acrescentar mais informações neste tópico, as respostas poderão ser mais precisas. A existência da coluna job_id, por exemplo, pode afetar as respostas. Ela é do tipo autoincremento?

Comment: @JoséDiz Tudo bem! Quando chegar em casa eu vou documentar melhor a pergunta para que agente tenha respostas melhores também. Peço desculpas!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para ter ação semelhante à construção [REPLACE INTO](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replace.html) (extensão SQL do MySQL) mencionada neste tópico, eis esboço do código:

```
-- código #1
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
DELETE from [schedule]
       where jobname = 'sqldump';
INSERT into [schedule] (jobname, last_exec_date)
       values ('sqldump', Cast(Current_timestamp as date)); 
COMMIT;
```

O código acima assume que a coluna jobname é a chave primária da tabela [schedule]. A finalização depende das respostas pendentes do autor do tópico.

Caso a coluna last_exec_date seja do tipo *datetime* (data e hora), deve-se retirar o Cast(), ficando somente Current_timestamp.

Para decidir com certeza como substituir o REPLACE INTO nesse caso, recomenda-se analisar qual é a ação efetiva dele no código que está migrando de MySQL para SQL Server.

Comment: esse é o mais simples e age como o replace into. Só tem um detalhe. Se excluir, todas as colunas são apagadas. No momento do intsert into, deve inseri-las novamente. Mas a pergunta nao deixa claro que há outras colunas. Para uma query mais consistente,  usa-se o merge com when matched..

Answer (score 2):

Assumindo que jobname seja a chave da tabela schedule

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [schedule ] WHERE jobname  = 'sqldump')
   UPDATE [schedule ] SET last_exec_date = GETDATE() WHERE jobname = 'sqldump'
ELSE
   INSERT INTO [schedule ] VALUES( 'sqldump', GETDATE() )
```

Comment: Acho que esta mais para o nome do job, mas sua resposta é boa.

Comment: @ReginaldoRigo: Acrescente a cláusula WHERE no comando UPDATE, definindo a linha a ser atualizada.

Comment: Tem razão. Falha minha.

Comment: nesse exemplo é diferente do que realmente faz o `replace into`. Isso é equivalente ao `on duplicate`

Answer (score -1):

A função função `NOW()` troque por `GETDATE()`

No código da pergunta, a sintaxe está errada:

```
REPLACE INTO schedule SET jobname = "sqldump" , last_exec_date = NOW()
```

No MySQL a sintaxe correta deveria ser

```
REPLACE INTO schedule (jobname, last_exec_date) VALUES ('sqldump', NOW())
```

Note que `REPLACE INTO` é uma sintaxe do MySQL, a qual não faz parte do SQL standard.

Para entender como traduzir o comando corretamente, é preciso entender o que o `REPLACE INTO` faz.

O `REPLACE INTO` exclui o row inteiro se encontra uma chave duplicada e então faz o `INSERT`.

Para esse comportamente, no SQL SERVER, deve criar uma lógica onde aplica o `DELETE` e em seguida o `INSERT`. Ou seja, duas queries separadas.

Para garantir consistência, execute dentro de um `TRANSACTION`.

## ON DUPLICATE KEY (MySQL)

Há recomendações para o uso de `ON DUPLICATE KEY` alternativamente ao `REPLACE INTO`. No entanto, a decisão é do desenvolvedor.
Esse comando não deleta o row. Quando encontra uma chave duplicada, faz um UPDATE.

Infelizmente o SQL SERVER não provê esse tipo de recurso.

Para casos onde não queira excluir e inserir é o recomendado.

No SQL Server pode combinar o comando `MERGE` com `WHEN MATCHED`.

```
MERGE schedule AS T
using (VALUES ('sqldump', GETDATE()))
    AS S (jobname, last_exec_date)
    ON T.jobname = 'sqldump'
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE
    set last_exec_date = S.last_exec_date
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (jobname, last_exec_date)
    VALUES (7, S.jobname, S.last_exec_date)
```

Nesse exemplo usei `jobname` como coluna de chave primária. Não está claro na pergunta a estrutura da tabela. Então pressuponho que seja essa coluna.

**Nota:**

O cuidado em usar *delete* e *insert* é que no momento do *insert* deve inserir todas as colunas existentes. Portanto deve estar ciente do que realmente precisa.

Comment: Desculpe-me, mas não há REPLACE INTO no SQL-Server

Comment: Editei para evitar confusão, o que invalida esse seu comentario, @ReginaldoRigo